# How to auto-number a flow chart (created by 'tikz' package ) like a figure using 'graphicx'?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, flow-charts, autonum

I have created a flow chart in Latex by 'tikz' package. Besides, there are many figures in my paper, and I used  'graphicx' package to auto-number these figures.

However, if I want to auto-number the flow chart together with other inserted figures, could anyone please help me how to achieve that?

I put my code of flow chart here:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
\tikzstyle{startstop} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm,text centered, draw=black, fill=white]
\tikzstyle{io} = [trapezium, trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=white]
\tikzstyle{process} = [rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=white]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]



\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]

\node (in1) [io] {unit cell};
\node (pro1) [process, below of=in1] {vc-relax (pw.x)};

\draw[arrow](in1)--(pro1);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

And my code for auto-number figure:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}


\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics{a.jpeg}
    \caption{Caption}
\end{figure}
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Place the `tikzpicture` inside of a `figure` environment.

Comment: The `graphicx` package has nothing to do with the figure environment and caption numeration. Demonstration:  `\documentclass{article}
\begin{document} \begin{figure} \hfil whatever \caption{caption of whatever} \end{figure} \end{document}`

Comment: @leandriis Thanks! It works!!!

Comment: @Fran that is the answer (and this is a common misconception so I think it is worth an answer not just close as "solved in comments") do you want to post it as an answer? oh or leandris :-)

Answer (score 2):

The `graphicx` package allow the insertion of external images (in png, jpg or pdf format using `pdflatex`, or eps format using `latex`) with the `\includegraphics` command, but this has nothing to do with the `figure` environment, that can be used without any package,  and without any image:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
     \hfil  (whatever) 
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

That is, the `figure` environment is not an image, as the `table` environment in not really a table. Both are floats, unbreakable containers that can move from the actual position to fit well on top or bottom of the present page, or move to the next page if this is not possible, according to some options and complex rules. For a full understanding  of floating mechanisms, see      [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat).

The numeration of the float is due to the optional  `\caption{...}` command, that will increase the float counter and print "Figure x" or "Table y" plus the argument (the `{...}` part), that is,  `\figurename` plus `\thefigure`, or `\tablename` plus `\thetable`, according to the type of float where it is placed, without regarding the float content:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
      \hfil  (whatever) 
      \caption{caption of whatever}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

In both floats types, the content of the float is up to you. It can be almost anything except another float (a nested float is a contradiction in its own terms, and of course, will produce a fatal error), so the content can be an image in a `table` environment,  or a <s>table</s> tabular environment in a `figure` environment, or absolutely nothing, or some text with or without a caption, or a minipage,  ... or a tikz draw, that answer the question in verbose mode, but not better than the @leandriis comment:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
\tikzstyle{startstop} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm,text centered, draw=black, fill=white]
\tikzstyle{io} = [trapezium, trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=white]
\tikzstyle{process} = [rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=white]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}\centering 
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]
\node (in1) [io] {unit cell};
\node (pro1) [process, below of=in1] {vc-relax (pw.x)};
\draw[arrow](in1)--(pro1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{A tikz figure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer. I try to vote it, but my reputation is low so it didn't show! Anyway, thanks!